# How to sort alphanumeric column from SQL Server with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some data stored in SQL Server like this :

```
A1
A2
A3
1A
2A
3A
```

How can sort it?

I tried this query:

```
select name
from Analyze_Table
group by name
order by CONVERT(INT, LEFT(name, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name+'z')-1)),name
```

but this only sorts by the first number and after alphabetic and doesn't sort alphabetic and after number values

Comment: Please explain what you want your results to be.

Comment: Where does C# fit into the picture? If you're trying to sort the results in SQL then C# is irrelevant. It would be different if you wanted to get the results back from SQL and then sort them. Aside from that, you could really help everyone out by taking those six things and showing the order you want them to be in after sorting.

Comment: Could you have a value like `'10A'`? What about `'A10'` or even `'1A10'`? What order should they appear in your data?

Comment: @Larnu my value is numbers+char or char+numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to sort on just the numeric portion of the name, excluding the first or last character. Then if there are 2 with the same number, they will sort again, e.g. 23 and 23A. This should give you the output you were looking for

```
select name
from Analyze_Table
group by name
order by case 
  when isnumeric(name) = 1 then cast(name as int)
  when isnumeric(left(name, 1)) = 0 and isnumeric(right(name, 1)) = 0 then cast(substring(name, 2, len(name)-2) as int)
  when isnumeric(left(name, 1)) = 0 then cast(right(name, len(name)-1) as int)
  when isnumeric(right(name, 1)) = 0 then cast(left(name, len(name)-1) as int) end
  ,name
```

Comment: we received error : Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: Edited to add -1, try it again

Comment: What is the result you expecting? How do you want those 6 rows sorted? Can you please post your expected output?

Comment: my code is return :   E103,E33,E99,E80,21,22,23,23A,25,26A

Comment: but i need to : E33,E80,E99,E103,21,22,23,23A,25,26A

Comment: So you need letters before number? How is E103 before 21?.. So you first want to sort by the first letter (A,B,C,D) then numbers, then just numbers such as (21,22,23,23A)? Sorry you weren't clear

Comment: yes but if result is : 21,22,23,23A,25,26A,E33,45,68A,E70 its very good

Comment: @HadiRanji please see my updated answer which will output the way you want

Comment: i have this error : Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '26A' to data type int.

Comment: I tested this SQL script with all these values and it works fine 21,22,23,23A,25,26A,E33,45,68A,E70. Are there other values you are testing against? Are there some names that have more than 1 letter at the start or the end?

Comment: sorry i have value like this E26A

Comment: OK let me adjust the script to handle this case

Comment: @HadiRanji please check the answer now

Comment: if have value like this : 518-1 how can sort after value 518 ?

Comment: I'll leave that one for you, it sounds like you have a lot of different variants. Look at the SQL documentation for the CASE statement and the SUBSTRING statement. You can then perform all the cases you need.

Comment: when charindex('-',name)>0 then cast(left(name, charindex('-',name)-1) as int)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the names that start with numbers first, then is this what you what?

```
order by (case when name like '[0-9]%' then 1 else 2 end),
         name
```